# Choosing the best set of features when forced to choose M out of N available features

Tags: neural-network, classification, feature-selection

Given: N features that map to some label Y using a Neural Net(NN)- it's a classification problem.

Problem: I want to get away by using only a subset of features denoted by M, where M<N.

Now I am free to choose any of the $\frac{N!}{(M!*(N-M!))}$
available features to achieve this.
But I want the set of features that maximizes my prediction accuracy when I use these new features in a NN to map to label Y.

How do I do this?